# Local variable may not have been intitialized- Android Project

Tags: java, android

I've been working on an Android calculator for the past several days. I've reached the equals button, which is the last part of my code. But it is saying theOperator is not initialized for some reason at my if statement. Any help?

[code]
    package rechee.cool;

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     public EditText display;

    double counter1=0;
    double counter2=0;

    String display1= display.getText().toString();


    String sub = "-";
    String divide = "/";

    String mult = "*";


    //Just have two buttons so far, I'm going to have like 10 more







    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Associate the button variable with the xml reference



        display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);}




        //When button is clicked, display the text. How do I do this for the rest of my variables?


            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.bOne:
                    display.append("1");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bTwo:

                        display.append("2");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bThree:
                        display.append("3");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bFour:
                        display.append("4");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bFive:
                        display.append("5");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bSix:
                        display.append("6");
                        break;

                    case R.id.bSeven:
                        display.append("7");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bEight:
                        display.append("8");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bNine:
                        display.append("9");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bZero:
                        display.append("0");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bPoint:
                        display.append(".");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bClear:
                        display.setText("");
                        break;
                    case R.id.bAdd:
                    double displayValue= Double.parseDouble(display1);
                        counter1+= displayValue;
                        display.setText("");
                        String theOperator= new String("+");




                        break;
                    case R.id.bEqual:

                        //display.setText(Double.toString(counter2));
                        //counter1 = 0;
                        // Tried using a switch for theOperator, but 1.6 doesn't allow string switch. So I'm going to use if else statements instead.
                        if(theOperator=="+"){



                        }

                        }
                        //case "+":
                    //break;





                        }





                }
```

[/code]

Comment: Looks like you want to know what the operator was before '=' is clicked.  If that's the case, you should make that a member variable as suggested by @Eng.Fouad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you define `theOperator` inside the scope of `case R.id.bAdd` only, and `case R.id.bEqual` block cannot see it. You can solve the problem by defining the variable `theOperator` outside the entire switch block or as a field to the whole class.

Comment: If I declare it out of the switch block, how will Equals know I'm talking about B.Add?

Answer (score 1):

```
String display1 = display.getText().toString();
```

It is too dangerous to declare the field variable with assignment here because `display` might not be initialized at that point, put it after the following code.

> display= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

EDITED:
Forget to mention `theOperator`, you should declare it outside the switch case because of the scope issue.